# PHP Real Estate Google Geocoder update V2 to V3

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have the following code (I didn't program this site originally), but not sure what it does as every time it runs it use to throw a google error 610 and why we need to update to V3, but now it skips to the else statement of 'Geocoding skipped'.  It was programs for Google Goecoding v2 and I am trying to update it to v3.  Like I said someone else did it and left and I am the one trying to fix it now that it is broken.

```
$geocode = !($listing  
    && $listing->getAddress1() == $commonFieldValues['address_1'] 
    && $listing->getAddress2() == $commonFieldValues['address_2'] 
    && $listing->getCity() == $commonFieldValues['city'] 
    && $listing->getState() == $commonFieldValues['state']
    && $listing->getZipCode() == $commonFieldValues['zip_code']
);

if($geocode) {
    $baseUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&key=' . OurMLS_Constants::getGoogleMapsApiKey();
    $url = $baseUrl . '&q=' . urlencode(join(', ', $listing->getAddressLines(true, true)));
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    if($xml !== false) {
        // Curious what the status codes mean see...
        // http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGeoStatusCode
        $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
        if($status != '200') {
            print "Google Maps geocode request returned with status code '$status'\n";
        } else {
            $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
            $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
            $latitude = (float) $coordinatesSplit[1];
            $longitude = (float) $coordinatesSplit[0];
            $listing->setLatitude($latitude);
            $listing->setLongitude($longitude);             
        }
    }
} else {
    print ', Geocoding skipped';
}
```

I have updated it to what I though would get me the same results in V3 (as the rest of the site and mapping works as long as we can pull Lat and Long into the database) (not paid to touch what isn't broken)

```
$geocode = !($listing  
    && $listing->getAddress1() == $commonFieldValues['address_1'] 
    && $listing->getAddress2() == $commonFieldValues['address_2'] 
    && $listing->getCity() == $commonFieldValues['city'] 
    && $listing->getState() == $commonFieldValues['state']
    && $listing->getZipCode() == $commonFieldValues['zip_code']
);

if($geocode) {
    $baseUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml';
    $url = $baseUrl . "?address=" . urlencode(join(', ', $listing->getAddressLines(true, true))) . "&sensor=false" ;
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    if($xml !== false) {
        $status = $xml->GeocodeResponse->status;
        if($status != 'OK') {
            print "Google Maps geocode request returned with status code '$status'\n";
        } else {
            $latitude = $xml->GeocodeResponse->geometry->location->lat;
            $longitude = $xml->GeocodeResponse->geometry->location->lng;
            $listing->setLatitude($latitude);
            $listing->setLongitude($longitude);
        }
    }
} else {
    print ', Geocoding skipped';
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is a cron job to pull the RETS feed and save to a DB and as it saves the information to a local DB it should geocode the address in the DB so when the listings are shown they have a google map.

I am really not sure what "$geocode = !(" does.  This loop does run for each address it pulls and everything works except the geocoding.

I am not sure why it was pulling and getting Status code but now it is just skipping it

here are the two xml files
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&q=1600%pennsylvania%20ave%20washington%20dc
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600%pennsylvania%20ave%20washington%20dc&sensor=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$geocode = !(...bunch of stuff...);` says "take that bunch of stuff and evaluate it as a boolean value (ie. true or false). Then negate it (ie. if it's true, make it false; if it's false, make it true)." Check out [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for more on logical operators.

So you need to start by looking at the stuff in the parentheses:

```
$listing  // does the listing object exist?
&& $listing->getAddress1() == $commonFieldValues['address_1']   // and does "address1" equal this other thing
&& $listing->getAddress2() == $commonFieldValues['address_2']   // and does "address2" equal this other thing 
&& $listing->getCity() == $commonFieldValues['city']   // and does "city" equal this other thing
&& $listing->getState() == $commonFieldValues['state']   // you get the picture...
&& $listing->getZipCode() == $commonFieldValues['zip_code']
```

If all that is true, then `$geocode` is going to be false (because of the `!` operator) and your geocoding is only going to take place if `$geocode` is true.

I don't know much about your code, but I'd interpret this as saying

> If I have a listing and the address **doesn't** match or the city **doesn't** match or the state **doesn't** match or the zip code **doesn't** match, then I need to geocode it.

So look at your `$listing` object (does it exist?) and your `$commonFieldValues` array (what are those values and are they what you expect them to be?).

Comment: First off Thank you for the answer to = !, I looked everywhere for what that could mean but could not find it. That would make sense, we don't want to over query Ggl Geocoding. 

I see what is going on, the RETS feed runs and saves the feed to a CSV file, then this php script runs, organizing it into our DB updating as need or creating new and it does not geocode updates to DB. Since everything is already in the DB when I run it trying to get the geocode, it should run on new listings only, hopefully, I will empty the DB out and try it when I have time this weekend and see.

Comment: Again thank you for the explanation because that alone helps, I have been reading this code for a few days just trying to understand what it does. I can code what people tell me but I usually like knowing what stuff does too if I am working on it.